# How to import check box field data?

Tags: import

How do I successfully import contact's check box field data?
I am using civicrm 4.6.19 and importing from csv.

I want to import the "is deceased" field
and the communication preferences...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a deceased column. If a person is deceased give the value 1, otherwise give the value 0.

Generally, 1 is checked 0 is unchecked for the check boxes.